# Вопрос про Tilemap в Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Существует два Tilemap. Один Tilemap имеет order in Layer 1. Второй Tilemap имеет order in layer 0. Второй Tilemap имеет 5 объектов. Эти объекты не видны, так как у этого Tilemap order in layer меньше.

Когда главный персонаж натыкается на какой-нибудь из этих 5 объектов, order in layer этого объекта должен стать 2, чтобы этот объект стал виден.

Вопрос возможно ли сделать так чтобы только у одного объекта Tilemap, с которым произошло столкновение поменялся order in layer, а у остальных четырёх объектов order in layer остался таким же?

```
   private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
    {
        if (collision.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder == 0)
        {
            collision.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sortingOrder = 2;
        }
    }
```

Я смог написать код для просто спрайта объекта, но не понимаю, как переделать для Tilemap.